# React Native Build for android fails on windows machine

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am unable to run any react native app for android on my windows machine, I followed all steps stated on the official documentation but still doest work. I keep getting this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.util.zip.ZipException
```

I'm using the latest version of NPM and React Native as of this time.
I need to know how to fix this so the app builds successfully and runs on my virtual or real device, thanks.

[image: CLI Build Error]

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace of error can be summarized to `java.util.zip.ZipException: Error opening zip file`.

This can happen when exposing a **corrupted** `jar` file.

Checkout the libraries you are adding to the project. **The JAR files should be intact and not corrupted.**